# TcpWindowSize vs Socket Buffer Size on Windows

Tags: tcp, network-programming

What is difference between TcpWindowSize and Socket Buffer Sizes ?

I assume TcpWindowSize can be changed only using Registry Settings and Socket Buffer Sizes can be changed using SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF socket parameters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14381789/3134621

Comment: @deviantfan Not the same thing. This question is about the TcpWindowSize Registry entry.

Comment: See [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938219.aspx) for the registry entry.

Comment: @EJP: I didn´t mean the question in the first place. But the answer explains the difference.

Comment: @EJP: Why this question is about registry entries? "What is difference between TcpWindowSize and Socket Buffer Sizes ? I assume...". The OP thinks that they are the same thing, only global/local configuration.

Comment: @deviantfan TcpWindowSize *is* a Registry key, whether you know it or not. See the question itself, and also the MSDN link I posted. The other answer doesn't explain the difference between this registry key and the two socket options mentioned: it isn't about Registry settings at all. The OP doesn't 'think they are the same thing'. He is asking what the difference is. You're not reading anything here attentively enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The TcpWindowSize Registry setting controls the maximum advertised window of the interface as described in the [MSDN link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938219.aspx). Being a Registry setting, you change it in the Registry.
2. SO_RCVBUF controls the size of the socket receive buffer. This is the maximum advertised TCP window of the *connection,* and it is evidently subject to overriding by (1).
3. SO_SNDBUF controls the size of the socket send buffer. It doesn't have anything directly to do with windowing.