# Forcing TCP socket to a specific window size

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am sending TCP messages among apart DCs (`RTT`: 27 ms).

Having a Gigabit network (1Gb/s), I decided to put `RWIN` of 3 MB.

I know how to modify `net.core.rmem_max` and `net.core.wmem_max`.

I checked that window scaling is enabled `net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1`.

However, what I want to know: is it able to modify the window size manually or it is done automatically. Please explain.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381303/increasing-tcp-window-size

Comment: Thank you dear. This is the first google result. I already checked that. @EJP said that: "The maximum dynamic window size is determined by the size of the socket receive buffer at the target and the window scaling in effect if any". I wanted to make sure there is no other way. Moreover, the answer is 3 years old. Probably, there is some update.

Comment: Unfortunately, the over 1500 pages that make up the current C++ standard make absolutely mention of anything called a "socket". This has nothing to do with C++, the language. Sockets are a feature, a resource, provided by the operating system, so for answer to this question, check your operating system's documentation. Although you haven't specified your OS, based on the references in the question it's like to be Linux or Unix. A brief review of the contents of the socket(7) man page finds no means of setting these TCP options. This is something that's handled entirely by the kernel.

Comment: Dear agg. @SamVarshavchik: Afaik, there is no net.core.wmem_max in MAC nor in Windows. It is very trivial so i didn't mention it.

Comment: @usr: because I am trying to throttle the network and benchmark an algoithm. but the latency is respectively high which decreases the throughput (According to BDP rule).

Comment: @Mohamad-jaafar There is no update. TCP was defined in 1979. The window is controlled for you. There is nothing you have to do except set it before you connect.

Comment: @EJP, ok thanks dear.

Comment: @kometen This question has nothing specifically to do with C++ or indeed any programming language. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: @EJP OK. Assumed OP wanted to set it from C++. Heading has also been corrected since I tagged it.

Comment: Any update on this case?

Comment: @Pujianto, have a look on this please. It doesn't directly address my concern, but it's so close. https://www.cadc-ccda.hia-iha.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/netperf/tuning-tcp.shtml

Comment: @Jaafar Hi, thanks for the link. 
Finally, I am using Netfilter queue to forward the raw IP traffic to user space. Then I can modify the TCP traffic in there.