# Sending Image data at high data rate over boost::asio::udp?

Tags: c++, image, sockets, boost, udp

I have images that are 4MB large that must be sent over Ethernet.   The images come from one computer, X86_64, which generates them, and are sent to another computer, ARM.  Images are generated at double digit frame rates, and I'm using cat 6a cables to ensure I can get enough data at a reasonable speed. I'm having trouble understanding what kind of utilities boost lets me use to send arbitrarily sized data over UDP, and recieve it on the other end.  Both computers have Boost installed, both are linux (but different distros). Individual image loss is not all that important, but it is important to have the whole image sent or rejected.

- Do I have to manually segment data to be sent over?
- How do I deal with image packet loss if this is the case? as in how would I be able to tell what the end of my image is? Do I have to tag each packet with the row of the image it corresponds to?
- Does boost have utilities to handle arbitrary data sends over UDP?

After attempting to do this my self (tagging each row with a row identifier) it appears that I'm over-saturating some buffer (the tags are sequential up until a certain point, where they start jumping up in number monotonically, so no reordering, but packet loss) Note this is on local host, so I'm not sure what I should be expecting.

I can't seem to find a way around massive image loss, but I'm not sure if that is just because of some network cable limitation (despite sending to and receiving on local host?).

I'd move to TCP, but I would need to be assured that I could get 200MB/s via direct Ethernet connection on the other end reliably. The time before images start be sent is less important than the overall throughput in a given second.

Slightly simplified code I made for this:

## sending images

```
// sender.cpp

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include "PgmImage.h"

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

const std::string &host = "localhost";
const std::string &port = "8000";
const int image_width = 2048;
const int image_height = 2048;

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        udp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), host, port);
        udp::endpoint receiver_endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
        udp::socket send_socket(io_service);
        send_socket.open(udp::v4());
        boost::array<std::uint16_t, 2> send_header_buffer;
        boost::array<std::uint8_t, image_height + 2> send_row_buffer;
        auto time1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j) {
            for (const auto &file_path : file_path_list) {
                // reads in image and has a vector member of char. 
                PgmP5Image image("../short_armcam_clip/" + file_path);
                send_header_buffer = {image.width(), image.height()};
                send_socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(send_header_buffer), receiver_endpoint);
                for (std::uint16_t i = 0; i < image_height; i++) {
                    send_row_buffer[0] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(i >> 8);
                    send_row_buffer[1] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(i);
                    std::copy(&image.getRawBytes()[i * image_width],
                              &image.getRawBytes()[i * image_width + image_width], &send_row_buffer[2]);
                    send_socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(send_row_buffer), receiver_endpoint);
                    if (i % 64 == 0) {
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>(1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        auto time2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "took : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time2 - time1).count() << "millis"
                  << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## receiving images

```
// receiver.cpp

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        udp::socket socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 8000));
        udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;

        boost::array<std::uint16_t, 2> recv_header_buffer;
        boost::array<std::uint8_t, 2050> recv_row_buffer;
        int num_recieved = 0;
        while (true) {
            boost::system::error_code error;
            socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_header_buffer), remote_endpoint, 0, error);
            if (error && (error != boost::asio::error::message_size)) {
                throw boost::system::system_error(error);
            }
            int width = recv_header_buffer[0];
            int height = recv_header_buffer[1];
            std::cout << "width : " << width << " height : " << height << std::endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
                socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_row_buffer), remote_endpoint, 0, error);
                if (error && (error != boost::asio::error::message_size)) {
                    throw boost::system::system_error(error);
                }
                std::uint16_t row = (recv_row_buffer[0] << 8) + recv_row_buffer[1];

                std::cout << "row : " << row << " processed " << std::endl;
                std::cout << "i : " << i << std::endl;
                if (row != i) {
                    break;
                }
                if (i == 2047) {
                    num_recieved += 1;
                    std::cout << "Num received: " << num_recieved << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Do I have to manually segment data to be sent over?

Yes, you do. You should segment them so each segment fits in an Ethernet packet (1536 bytes - ethernet + ip + udp headers), this is a bit inconvenient, but all segments can be put passed as an vector of vectors in an asio::buffer to async_write().

> - How do I deal with image packet loss if this is the case? as in how would I be able to tell what the end of my image is? Do I have to tag each packet with the row of the image it corresponds to?

You would have to number each packet, a packet # would be enough, but your error handling would probably end up making your transfers slower than tcp.

> - Does boost have utilities to handle arbitrary data sends over UDP?

Boost does not, to my knowledge have any ready-made facilities that would help you to stream data over UDP.

I think your best bet is to use TCP, which handles streaming for maximum speeed and gives you some extra insurance for data integrity.

> - I'd move to TCP, but I would need to be assured that I could get 200MB/s via direct Ethernet connection on the other end reliably. The time before images start be sent is less important than the overall throughput in a given second.

There is only one way to check this, and that is running tests over your network, between the actual host and target.  The answer to that question depends on network hardware and topology, NIC device drivers, and machine loads.

Note that TCP would probably give you the highest throughput possible. You would not have to segment your data into packets yourself, and you'd then get the maximum possible performance from boost::asio.

Comment: After testing TCP I was getting odd performance gains, so I've switched to TCP now

Comment: It's becase TCP does streaming.  You can fine tune your application for best throughput by playing with the sockets TCP window size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381303/increasing-tcp-window-size